# What is the pattern for mathematic sequence?

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck to [Problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) of Project Euler, which makes use of the fibonnacci sequence.

My first naive implementation was grounded on the sheer math definition, using a recursive function:

```
fibonnacci_coefficient :: (Eq a, NUm a) => a -> a
fibonnacci_coefficient n
    | n == 0 = 1
    | n == 1 = 2
    | otherwise = fibonnacci_coefficient (n-1) + fibonnacci_coefficient (n-2)
```

The exercise is asking to sum the even coefficients, those not exceeding 4,000,000.  When I launched my algorithm it took more than 45 minutes so I canceled it. I guess it's because of my using this function that depends for each steps on re-computing former element recursively.

Among my readings I happened to see an 'efficient' definition of the fibonnacci sequence:

```
fib = 1 : 2 : [ a+b | (a,b) <- zip fib (tail fib)]
```

Honestly, I feel, I see why it works. I see, I kind of understand, but I cannot intuitively switch from the math definition directly to such an Haskell definition.

As I understood, efficiency relies in the main concept to define a list that chases its tail. But I can't grasp the pattern. And to understand I think I need to see the whole pattern:

Given a math sequence, that depends on k indexes, let's say k=4, given function f that takes 4 arguments:

```
u(n) = f (u(n-1)) (u(n-2)) (u(n-3)) (u(n-4))
```

What would be the Haskell pattern to express this list as an infinite list / sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was mentioned that it is not easy to write such a function that works for all `k` simultaneously.  This is true if you want it to be type safe in the number of arguments.  However, if you are willing to let your function `f` take a *list* of arguments instead, then it is possible (stealing the function name from @bheklilr):

```
import Data.List (tails)

recSeqK :: Int -> ([a] -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
recSeqK k f firstN = l where
    l = firstN ++ map (f . reverse . take k) (tails l)

fib = recSeqK 2 sum [1,2]

main = print $ take 50 fib
```

Note that the `reverse` is only needed because it is easier to write this with the opposite argument order for `f` of the one in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the first four elements of the sequence are `a,b,c,d`, then `u(n) = f(u(n-1), u(n-2), u(n-3), u(n-4))` can be translated into a recursively-defined list in Haskell with:

```
u = a : b : c : d : zipWith4 f (tail (tail (tail u))) (tail (tail u)) (tail u) u
```

Comment: @StephaneRolland: The only other reasonable way I can think of to do this is by emulating the iteration of an imperative language using the `until` function or a custom recursive function with an index & accumulator as arguments — but that's not very Haskellish.

Comment: @StephaneRolland You can create a pattern much like jwodder has done for specific numbers of arguments, but with Haskell's type system it's quite difficult to have functions of an arbitrary number of arguments, you would probably need full dependent types or to just use a type system like Python's instead.  However, this sort of pattern is very rare, you wouldn't really need it in practice.  This is why `Prelude` has functions like `zipWith`, `zipWith3`, `zipWith4`, ... `zipWith7`.  It's an easy enough pattern to write when you need it, but not a common enough one to need a generalized form.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Then the most "Haskellish" way would be to write a pattern for a specific number of arguments.  So if you had a sequence recursive on one element, you'd have `recSeq :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`, for two elements `recSeq2 :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> [a]`, etc.  This would match what `Prelude` has done with similar patterns, such as `zipWith`.  [This would be how I would implement such a pattern for up to 4 arguments](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/16c5f7e82fbc900c3e4b). I've added lots of whitespace to try to make it more readable, but feel free to compress it down if you want

Answer (score 2):

There's a function in Prelude called [`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) which enables you to define an infinite sequence based on repeated application:

```
-- example: natural numbers
nats :: [Integer]
nats = iterate (+1) 0
```

`iterate` is implemented as

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)
```

How does this work? Well, we use the current value as new element for our resulting list, and call iterate again with `f x` as new current value. We can use this pattern to define other `iterate` variants with more arguments:

```
iterate2 :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> [a]
iterate2 f x y = x : iterate2 f y (f x y)

iterate3 :: (a -> a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a -> [a]
iterate3 f x y z = x : iterate3 f y z (f x y z)

iterate4 :: (a -> a -> a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a -> a -> [a]
iterate4 f a b c d = a : iterate4 f b c d (f a b c d)

-- and so on
-- example:
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = iterate2 (+) 0 1

-- note: arguments of f are from last to first, so
--       we need to reverse the order of arguments
u = iterate4 (\a b c d -> f d c b a) x y v w
```

However, as you can see, the stepping function has another type, depending on how many previous values we want to use. That's also the reason we have `zipWith`, `zipWith3`, `zipWith4` and so on. While it is possible to create a typeclass in order to create a single function for a *fixed* number of instances, it isn't possible to do this for *arbitrary* sequences.

That being said, you're probably good with one of those simple functions.